# Best way to ask users for their location

Tags: ios, geolocation

Right now, users have to type in their location manually which cases a ton of problems with querying.

Instead, I would love to have something similar to Twitter's approach where the user begins to type in their location and a list of options show below:

[image]

Any idea on how this was done? I'm assuming that Twitter uses some sort of locations API to get a list of different city + state pairs

Comment: It's a variation of the local search autocomplete. Apple has some sample code here: [Searching for Nearby Points of Interest](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/searching_for_nearby_points_of_interest). If you use Google Maps, check the [Place Autocomplete API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete)

Comment: [`MKLocalSearchCompleter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mklocalsearchcompleter).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if Twitter is using this, but I used [Google Place Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/autocomplete). It's easy to install and it might help.